# How to Open an Intellitrace file?

Tags: .net, intellitrace

when I try to open an itrace file I get "problem sending the command to the program"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Ultimate. It turns out that you need to open the .itrace file from visual studio with the matching solution open beforehand.

Comment: I'm using Ultimate too; Have the solution open, clicked File->Open File, tried to open the .itrace file, got "The operation could not be completed".